# Load data from db2 table to informatica

Tags: oracle, db2, informatica

I want to load data from a `db2` table to oracle table using informatica.

My db2 table has column `update_user_timestamp` which has latest update timestamp stored in it. I want to load the data having timestamp of previous month only.

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put something like below in the where condition of your source qualifier query:

```
month(update_user_timestamp) = month(current timestamp - 1 month)
```